# BASH: Iterate range of numbers in a for cicle

Tags: bash, shell, variables, for-loop, tail

I want to create an array from a list of words. so, i'm using this code:

```
for i in {1..$count} 
do
array[$i]=$(cat file.txt | cut -d',' -f3 | sort -r | uniq | tail -n ${i})
done
```

but it fails... in `tail -n ${i}`

I already tried `tail -n $i`, `tail -n $(i)` but can't pass tail the value of `i`

Any ideas?

Comment: where do you set the value for `$count`? Good luck.

Comment: You could say `for i in $(seq $count)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because you cannot use a variable in range directive in shell i.e. `{1..10}` is fine but `{1..$n}` is not.

While using BASH you can use `((...))` operators:

```
for ((i=1; i<=count; i++)); do
   array[$i]=$(cut -d',' -f3 file.txt | sort -r | uniq | tail -n $i)
done
```

Also note removal of *useless use of cat* from your command.

Comment: If i replace <tail -n $i> for <sed '$i!d'> the script fails!

Comment: Better to show complete command line so that I can help better.

Comment: i think i solved it... i was doing <cut -d',' -f3 file.txt | sort -r | uniq | sed -n '$ip'> and it didn't work. tried <cut -d',' -f3 file.txt | sort -r | uniq | sed -n "$i p"> and seems to work fine. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your range is not evaluated the way you are thinking, e.g.:

```
$ x=10
$ echo {1..$x}
{1..10}
```

You're better off just using a for loop:

```
for ((i = 1; i <= count; i++))
do
   # ...
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on previous answers, this occurs because the 'brace expansion' is the first part of bash's parsing, and never gets repeated: when the braces are expanded, the '$count' is just a piece of text and so the braces are left as is. Then, when '$count' is expanded to a number, the brace expansion never runs again. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions).

If you wanted for some reason to force this brace expansion to happen again, you can use 'eval':

replace the `{1..$count}` with `$(eval echo {1..${count}})`

Better, in your case, to do as anubhava suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading the file numerous times, use the [built-in `mapfile` command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile):

```
mapfile -t array < <(cut -d, -f3 file.txt | sort -r | uniq)
```

Comment: Although it's only implicit in the question, I think the intent is ... `sort -ur | head -n $count` to get only `$count` values. But who knows? Anyway, +1.